# Selenium - Use @FindBy and the traditional driver.findByElement in the same class

Tags: java, selenium

Hi guys I was using @FindBy annotation for my object addresses, and in the base class i.e parent class for all the pages i had initalized the pagefactory like shown below:

BasePage:

```
public BasePage(WebDriver driver){

      PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

Subpage:

```
@FindBy(id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_physicianList")

WebElement myElement;
```

Now so far everything worked fine.

Now i need to append some parameters to the address since i need it for some logic implementations.

Since `@FindBy` can only be used for static addresses i decided to use the traditional `driver.findElementBy`...

Something like below:

```
WebElement report = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00" + noOfPatients + "_LinkButton2"));
```

But when i run this i get a nullpointer exception.

Its not an issue with the address as i have tried hardcoding the above id and making it static like below :

ctl004_LinkButton2

I still run into the nullpointer exception whereas when i try the static with the `@FindBy` it works fine.

Could someone please provide some input.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys I figured out what was the problem. I was getting the value of driver as null hence the nullpointer exception. I had added an Webdriver driver implementation in the subclass a while back which i had forgotten to remove. This was causing the issue.

Comment: You should accept your answer and it will close the question then.